# Página do GraphiQL Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

Tenho o GraphQL na máquina de dev Local junto com o a gem GraphiQL onde posso fazer minhas consultas, mas no servidor de testes eu não consigo acessar esta página `.../graphiql`.

Fica a tela branca escrito `Loading...` e nunca carrega.

Estou usando

```
Ruby 2.2.10
Rails 3.2.22
```

As gems estão todas instaladas nos dois ambientes;
Retorna um erro no console do browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use e "__Schema" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
```

Segue trecho do gemfile que refere-se ao graphQL

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :staging, :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end

gem 'test-unit'
gem 'graphql'
group :development, :master do
  gem 'graphiql-rails' 
end

Comment: Olá. Posta aqui o seu Gemfile também.

Comment: Está é a parte que se refere ao graph



group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :staging, :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end

gem 'test-unit'
gem 'graphql'
group :development, :master do
  gem 'graphiql-rails' 
end

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei formatar o seu Gemfile e obtive isso:

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'pry-byebug' 
end 

group :staging, :production do 
  gem 'unicorn'  
  gem 'test-unit' 
  gem 'graphql'
end

group :development, :master do 
  gem 'graphiql-rails'
end
```

Se for isso mesmo, o problema é porque o `graphiql-rails` não está no seu grupo do servirdor de teste (que imagino que seja o `staging`).

### **Conselhos:**

1) Olhando esse arquivo eu removeria o `graphql` do grupo e deixaria ele na raiz pois independente da env você vai precisa do graphql.

2) Aqui no trabalho só deixamos o `graphiql` para development (segurança). Se precisarmos acessar o stages usamos alguma IDE de graphql:

- https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground
- https://github.com/andev-software/graphql-ide
- https://github.com/imolorhe/altair
- https://insomnia.rest/

Comment: Obrigado por responder, Rafael Gomes!

Certo, realmente já reformatei isso.

Por incrível que pareça aqui o servidor de testes é o master. rsrss

Eu gostaria de deixar o graphiql para que meus parceiros pudessem ter acesso à consultas, estrutura de dados, aos comentários... Que me dá na verdade uma documentação da API.

Comment: Esta IDE da graphql-ide me pareceu bem interessante, vou instalar para ver se me atende.

Obrigado. abç!

Comment: Entendo.
Uma solução seria fazer o clientes se conectarem via IDE também. Você fornece a URL e a pessoa se vira.
Mas pensando e facilidade, realmente, o GraphiQL mataria. Como eu disse: Se deixar essa gem fora dos `group`s e deixa ele no escopo geral talvez já resolva pra ti.

Se ajudou, por favor, marque a resposta como correta.
Abraços!